# S.P.E.C.I.A.L. intro videos

Tags: fallout-4

Some days ago (I think it was last Sunday if that's relevant) I got quite a surprise when starting Fallout 4: Instead of the usual "Please stand by", I got a cute little video explaining one of the S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats, in that case it was explaining Luck. I have not got such an intro since, but I expect there to be more, at least one for each stat.

Are there indeed more of those videos, and if so, can I trigger them somehow?

Comment: Downvoting due to lack of research. But these videos are all quite old; they were used for promoting fallout 4, and play during the initial installation. Generally upvote if OP consolidates answers into one of higher quality

Comment: Granted. But i did not want to be spoiled by any promotional material, so i did not look anything up before the release of the game. I was honestly surprised at seeing that video on starting the game.

Comment: Its worth noting that each video acts as a goos introduction to each statistic,and what it will impact. Honestlyz watching them all gives you a beyter chance of putting together your ideal character. i have seen a friend delete their 10 hour + character because they were initially unsure of how to allocate these points

Answer (score 7):

You're right: There is a video for every SPECIAL stat. They are "triggered" simply by booting the game; after the Bethesda logo you will probably get shown one of them at random. However, this doesn't mean you have to keep booting the game to watch them all - just head over [here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/watch-every-fallout-4-special-stats-video/1100-6431729/).

Comment: The videos do not always play. In fact, for me, they only play if there is a problem with memory, forxing a slower load.

Comment: @Timelord64 I seem to get shown them at random. It doesn't really matter, the point is that they exist and are sometimes played on startup

Comment: @Timelord64 What happens when they don't play? Every time I've booted the game, I get these videos until I press a button.

Comment: @DCShannon Most of the time i get a "Please Stand By" message, followed by the Bethesda logo, then followed by the zoom in to the power armor with the press any button prompt. I find it quite curios that you get a video everytime, whereas i had it only pop up once yet.

Comment: @Ranayna I'm on Xbox One, that might make a difference.

Comment: On XB1. Videos do not play consistently on load. In fact, it's rare that I see one at all. Not sure what the trigger is.

Answer (score 2):

[Watch all seven S.P.E.C.I.A.L. videos on the official Bethesda YouTube channel](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSHdOA4o6T_c5iqXrXBIchAy78lPpZ9QY)